# comparing number of line written in csv to resultset row count

Tags: java, opencsv

I need to make sure that the csv I create from sql resultset dump using opencsv api is successful operation or not.
Right now I am using CSVWriter to write into the csv , now how would I use the CSVReader to read the line count in csv (assuming each resultset row is saved in 1 line in CSV) and compare that count with the resultset row count.
If the two are same its a success or else a failure.

I am dumping the full resultset into the csv file as follows

```
           File csvfile = new File ("erpimport_"+ getDateTimeString()+ ".csv");
           CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(csvfile), ',','"',';');
           boolean includeHeaders = true;
           ResultSet rs =  dbtype.executeQuery(sQuery);
           writer.writeAll(rs, includeHeaders);
           writer.close();
```

Is this check a valid method to test the success or failure of writing to csv?
also how would I get the line count in CSV using the CSVReader.

Thanks
Priyank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was verifying the functionality of an external library, I probably wouldn't use that same library to do it. A possible solution would be to scan through the file again with a `BufferedReader`, and make a count of the lines as you go, as follows:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new File("SomeFile.csv"));
int lineCount = 0;
while((String line = in.readLine()) != null)
    ++lineCount;
```

Then you could compare `lineCount` with your expected value. Of course this may not be the most efficient solution, depending on how frequently you want to perform this check, and the size of the files output.

Answer (score 0):

whether you can get the line number count depends upon the CSVReader/Writer you're speaking about -

I just checked and there are a bunch of them out there and they didn't seem to indicate any API call for getTotalLines() or some such though I didn't check each and every one of them: in the absence of support from the programs you are using,

For Mac/Linux, you could simply say: "wc -l ", without the quotes of course, to get the number of lines in the file

For windows, you could use:

@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=:" %%N in ('findstr /N /R "^" "APS-Cfiles.csv" ^| find /C ":"') do set lines=%%N

echo %lines%

Of course, don't forget to subtract 1 for the header line!

Best,
Shailen

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I need the check using java, cannot be OS specific implementation.

Comment: what does (CSVWriter).writeAll() return? Can you capture the value and let me know if it returns a number?

Also, as you probably already know, you can get the number of rows in the result set by using rs.getInt(0) ... if I remember correctly.

Btw, which java library are you using?